# Callbacks for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not running

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Going through the Code Lab for Firebase Android Friendly Chat - at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/ - I am running into an issue where none of the callbacks are being reached/called for step 7: **Read Messages**

Going through the /android-start project, I am able to get through the first steps 2-6:

1. Overview
2. Get the sample code
3. Import the starter app
4. Create Firebase console Project
5. Run the starter app
6. Enable Authentication *(android app added with package name and SHA1 via project console, etc)*

However, when I go to do step 7 - none of the callbacks there get called.  I run the app and the sign-in/out steps are working.

I have imported `initial_messages.json` as instructed there and copied over the code exactly for step 7 *(several attempts in an effort to make sure maybe I didn't miss something along the way)*.. and then even tried in the finished /android project.  There also, the same issue where callbacks never get run and so the spinner just hangs there.

Since there's so much code, I'll post the sections where I am expecting some callback to run.  Can anyone please advise on what I might be missing here? And no problem - if it will help to add more of the code I have. Thanks for reading

```java
    // mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
    // New child entries
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage> parser = new SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage>() {
        @Override
        public FriendlyMessage parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ... 
        }
    };
    ...

    DatabaseReference messagesRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD);

    ... 

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FriendlyMessage> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendlyMessage>()
                    .setQuery(messagesRef, parser)
                    .build();

    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            ... 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                        int position,
                                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage) {
            ....

        }
    };

    mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            ...
        }
    });


    mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 3.0 of FirebaseUI, a new [lifecycle policy for `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle) was introduced. Therefore, you are now required to explicitly call `startListening()` & `stopListening()` on the adapter to instruct it to start & stop retrieving data from the database.

From the [FirebaseUI 3.0 upgrade guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-3.0.md):

> Adapter Lifecycle - in previous versions the adapters began listening
>   immediately upon instantiation and had a `cleanup()` call to stop
>   listening. In 3.x you must explicitly call `startListening()` and
>   `stopListening()` or pass a `LifecycleOwner` to the options builder.

This is a very recent release and it looks like the Code Lab hasn't yet been updated to reflect this breaking change. I have raised this as [an issue on the `firebase/friendlychat-android` GitHub repo](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-android/issues/28).

Comment: I wasn't aware I should be checking with any upgrade guide .. good pointer there, as I didn't see it mentioned in the Code Lab .. hmm?   All that Code Lab code .. otherwise solid ..  simply this 1 missing line `mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();` and none of it was working.  I wasn't sure if I should even post this, thinking I must have missed something obvious.  I know we're supposed to avoid thank you comments - but in this case, you really caught an important issue I think; as I'm guessing many folks use those Code Labs .. saved my day for sure (Thank you)

Comment: Glad I could help! I know what you mean, it caught me out earlier this week and I couldn't believe this was the cure! This is especially strange though because I can't remember the code lab even mentioning that it uses FirebaseUI. Likewise, they recently [updated the dependencies of the sample code](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-android/commit/a88cd214e5528e17fd3c234d83589d85872650e2) but didn't add that very important method call! I guess that's what happens when libraries make breaking changes.